# Azure AD B2C signup userflow with two usernames

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on an ASP.Net application which will handle a type of user with two usernames. Example:

```
Username1: ABC
Username2: 123
Password: xxx
```

So when the user logs in it can log with ABC and the password or 123 and the password, both names leads me to the same user stored in Azure B2C.
Does anyone knows how to achieve it? I know it can be done becouse if I create it manually I can put the two usernames to the same user, but how to achieve that on a userflow?

Comment: AFAIK, the `User Principal Name` can be used to sign in. Which two usernames do you mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to sign up with two usernames on the userflow. This is the result of asking the azure engineer from Azure support.

You could just add usernames in the portal, but It is not recommended that you use multiple usernames.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Using the Local Account Idp it is possible to sign in either with Email or Username but not both, you can collect the user attributes as required (Default/custom) but it wont support for your requirement.